# ResultSetMetadata returning blank table names when using Group Concat?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can someone please explain to me what is going on? Just removing the group_concat function fixes the issue, but in this particular case I need it, alongside the table names in Java. Also, for some reason, it´s returning less rows then without group_concat.

I tried removing group_concat and editing it differently with group by and nothing happened.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Why would it show a table name? The data in the column created by `GROUP_CONCAT` does not have an underlying table. As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName(int)) says _"Returns: table name or "" if not applicable"_. In all the years I have worked with JDBC, I have probably only needed to know the table name of a column once, so are you actually sure you *really* need it.

Comment: And `GROUP_CONCAT` returning less rows is entirely expected, as it is an aggregate function, aggregating a group of rows into a single row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.